# Reading attributes when parsing XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have the following XML:

```
    <item>
        <media:content url="..." height="130" width="130" type="image/jpeg" />
        <media:credit role="provider"></media:credit>
        <media:text type="html"></media:text>
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        <description></description>
        <pubDate></pubDate>
        <category></category>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
    </item>
```

and the following code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: ... }).then(function (rss) {
    var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");

    for (var n = 0; n < items.length; n++) {
        var article = {};
        article.title = items[n].querySelector("title").textContent;
        var thumbs = items[n].querySelectorAll("media");
        article.content = items[n].querySelector("text").textContent;
        article.description = items[n].querySelector("description").textContent;
        if (thumbs.length > 1) {
            article.thumbnail = thumbs[0].attributes.getNamedItem("content");
        }
        else {
            var firstindex = article.content.indexOf("<img");
            if (firstindex !== -1) {
                var secondindex = article.content.indexOf("src=", firstindex) + 5;
                var thirdindex = article.content.indexOf("\"", secondindex);
                article.thumbnail = article.content.slice(secondindex, thirdindex);
            }
        }

        if (article.thumbnail) {
            list.push({ group: BasketballGroups[0], title: article.title, description: article.description, content: article.content, backgroundImage: article.thumbnail });
        }
    }
});
```

I keep getting an error at the following line: `article.content = items[n].querySelector("text").textContent;` -> `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference`

This is a Windows 8 Javascript App.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to select the `text` element from `<media:text>`?

Comment: It means that there is no `<title>` node in one of your `<item>` node.

Comment: How would I select the `<media:text>` element?

Comment: `document.querySelector("media\\:text")` [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/n45Vx/) maybe? (PS: `<title>` should be `<text>` in my previous comment.)

Comment: Now I get `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference` on the following line: `article.content = items[n].querySelector("media\\:text").textContent;`

Comment: Double checked, `media\\:text` doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems like `querySelector` [does not support](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Zb956/) namespaces (`media|text` is the correct selector), at least on Chrome it doesn't work.

Comment: `JavaScript runtime error: NamespaceError` when doing `article.content = items[n].querySelector("media|text").textContent;`